# Status bar icons, i3 window manager

Tags: window-manager, i3-wm

Is it possible show volume and wireless icons in the status bar, like in the Ubuntu title bar?

At moment I only connect to a unique wi-fi network, but in the future I need to see more networks.

Answer (score 2):

For WiFi applet, you need the package `network-manager-gnome`. To check is it is installed, do:

```
apt-cache policy network-manager-gnome
```

& check if it is installed.

---

For volume, you can see the volume percentage in your i3bar. First find the location of your `i3status.conf` file using the following command:

```
sudo find / -type f -iname .i3status.conf
```

Next, copy it to any folder of your choice. But for the sake of simplicity I am going to copy it to `~/.config/i3/`

```
cp /path/to/conffile ~/.config/i3/
```

Next, edit the `.i3status.conf` file. For volume these are the edits you should make:

- Uncomment this line:

  ```
  order += "volume master"
  ```
- Also, uncomment these lines:

  ```
  volume master {
          format = "♪: %volume"
          format_muted = "♪: muted (%volume)"
          device = "default"
          mixer = "Master"
          mixer_idx = 0
  }
  ```

Next, open your `config` file, find this pattern `status_command` and replace that line with this:

```
status_command i3status -c $HOME/.config/i3/.i3status.conf
```

If you want a volume applet instead of just an icon that shows you the volume percentage, then:

- Goto this [Github page](https://github.com/fernandotcl/pa-applet).
- Download the zip.
- Extract it to the folder of your choice.
- Compile it, by following the instructions given [here](https://github.com/fernandotcl/pa-applet/blob/master/INSTALL). Or follow these instructions (copied from the link):

  ```
  Dependencies
  ============

  Those are the dependencies needed to compile pa-applet:

  * GLib (libglib2.0-dev in Debian)
  * GTK+ >=3 (libgtk-3-dev in Debian)
  * libnotify (libnotify-dev in Debian)
  * libpulse (libpulse-dev in Debian)
  * Xlib (libx11-dev in Debian)
  * autoconf
  * automake
  * pkg-config


  Installation instructions
  =========================

  pa-applet uses autotools. If you're downloading from the Git repository, you might need to run autogen.sh before you compile it:

  $ ./autogen.sh

  Compiling and installing it is simple enough:

  $ ./configure --prefix=/foo/bar
  $ make
  $ make install
  ```

At the end of `~/.config/i3/config`, add these lines for the applet to work:

```
exec_always pa-applet
```

---

Also, for `nm-applet` just below the above line, look for the line:

```
tray_output primary
```

And make sure it is commented.

Also, add these lines at the end of `~/.config/i3/config` for the applet to show:

```
exec_always nm-applet
```

---

Finally, reboot.

Answer (score 1):

For volume I am using: [pnmixer](https://github.com/nicklan/pnmixer) 
And for network manager: [nm-applet](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/nm-applet.1.html)